# Comparing between two errors

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, I am throwing around errors by using the `Error` protocol. And there are many of these error types in my app such as `AuthError`, `ApiError`, etc. Not to mention the third-party frameworks's errors such as `RxCocoaURLError`, Twilio's `NSError`, etc. And then there is an enum to show/hide the error messages on the view:

```
enum ErrorMessageEvent {
    case hide
    case show(error: Error)
}
```

Now, in the unit test, I have a need to compare between two errors like so:

```
func testGetDataButtonTappedFailed_ShouldShowError() {
    let error = ApiError(type: .serviceUnavailable, message: "ABC")
    let viewModel = createViewModel(dataProvider: { _ in .error(error) })
    
    var actualErrorMessageEvent: ErrorMessageEvent?
    viewModel.errorMessageEvent
           .emit(onNext: { actualErrorMessageEvent = $0 })
           .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    
    viewModel.getDataButtonTapped(id: 1)
    
    XCTAssertEqual(.show(error: error), actualErrorMessageEvent)
}
```

Now when I added the `Equatable` to the `ErrorMessageEvent` and added this for the comparison func, but it always failed:

```
static func == (lhs: ErrorMessageEvent, rhs: ErrorMessageEvent) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.hide, .hide): return true
    case (.show(let lError), .show(let rError)): 
         return lError as AnyObject === rError as AnyObject
    default: return false
    }
}
```

What is the right way to compare those two errors and fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to test that the 2 error objects are the same instance?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I need to compare whether the passed error is the same (ie. the same type and data like localizedDescription, etc) with the actual error emitted from `viewModel.errorMessageEvent`. The only way I can think of is by comparing the instance because all the error type structs and enums are immutable so the data in them should also be the same if the instance is the same. That is what I think should happen. But instead, they are not the same instance. Or maybe the `Observable` that emits `errorMessageEvent` is not really using the same instance but just copied them instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First, make sure that each kind of error that you are dealing with properly conforms to `Equatable`**. Why are we using `Equatable` rather than `===`? Because the error types value types. `RxCocoaURLError` is an enum for example. And `===` never works on structs, even if you cast to `AnyObject`, because two different objects will be created when you do. Example:

```
enum Foo {
    case a(Int)
    case b(String)
}

(Foo.a(1) as AnyObject) === (Foo.a(1) as AnyObject) // false
```

The next step is to make `ErrorMessageEvent` generic (kind of like `Optional`, or half of `Result`):

```
enum ErrorMessageEvent<Failure: Error> {
    case hide
    case show(error: Failure)
    
    // this (tries to) changes the type of the error
    func mapError<T: Error>(toType type: T.Type) -> ErrorMessageEvent<T>? {
        switch self {
        case .hide:
            return .hide
        case .show(error: let e):
            return (e as? T).map(ErrorMessageEvent<T>.show)
        }
    }
}

// messages with an equatable error are also equatable
// the compiler will synthesise the implementation for us
extension ErrorMessageEvent : Equatable where Failure : Equatable {}
```

You can use `ErrorMessageEvent<Error>` for the type of observable for `viewModel.errorMessageEvent`. Then, when you want to compare errors in a test, you'd know which type of error you are comparing at that point, so you can do:

```
let error = ApiError(type: .serviceUnavailable, message: "ABC")

// ...

// I *think* it can infer the types. If not, write out the full "ErrorMessageEvent<ApiError>.show"
XCTAssertEqual(
    .show(error: error), 
    actualErrorMessageEvent?.mapError(toType: ApiError.self))
```

---

At this point, you might have realised. This is just reinventing the wheel of `Optional<T>`. So rather than `ErrorMessageEvent`, you can also consider an using an optional. Your `ErrorMessageEvent` might be overengineering.

```
let error = ApiError(type: .serviceUnavailable, message: "ABC")
let viewModel = createViewModel(dataProvider: { _ in .error(error) })

var actualErrorMessage: ApiError?
// viewModel.errorMessageEvent would be an Observable<Error?>
viewModel.errorMessageEvent
       .emit(onNext: { actualErrorMessage = $0 as? ApiError })
       .disposed(by: disposeBag)

viewModel.getDataButtonTapped(id: 1)

XCTAssertEqual(error, actualErrorMessageEvent)
```

It doesn't have as descriptive names as `show` and `hide` (It uses `none` and `some` instead), so if that's what you care about, I can understand.

Comment: Oh right. Structs and enums will just pass to the function by-value so it won't be the same instance. I forgot about that. Sorry, got a brain fart moment so what I imagined the code will be like in the memory is wrong. And your suggestion is really good. Using a generic, why didn't I think of that. Thanks a lot. And you are right, I want it to be more concise with hide / show.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on @Sweeper's answer, I came up with this custom assertion function instead:

```
func XCTAssertEqualGenericError<ErrorType: Equatable>(_ expected: ErrorType, 
                                                      _ actual: Error?,
                                                      file: StaticString = #file,
                                                      line: UInt = #line) throws {
    let actualError = try XCTUnwrap(actual as? ErrorType, file: file, line: line)
    XCTAssertEqual(expected, actualError, file: file, line: line)
}
```

And use it in this two assertions:

```
func XCTAssertErrorMessageEventHide(_ actual: ErrorMessageEvent?,
                                    file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    guard let actual = actual else {
        XCTFail("Actual ErrorMessageEvent is nil!")
        return
    }
    
    switch actual {
    case .show: XCTFail("Actual ErrorMessageEvent is not of the type .hide!")
    case .hide: return
    }
}

func XCTAssertErrorMessageEventShow<ErrorType: Equatable>(_ expected: ErrorMessageEvent,
                                                          _ actual: ErrorMessageEvent?,
                                                          errorType: ErrorType.Type,
                                                          file: StaticString = #file,
                                                          line: UInt = #line) throws {
    guard let actual = actual else {
        XCTFail("Actual ErrorMessageEvent is nil!")
        return
    }
    
    switch (expected, actual) {
    case (.hide, _):
        XCTFail("Expected ErrorMessageEvent is not of the type .show(_, _)!")
    case (_, .hide):
        XCTFail("Actual ErrorMessageEvent is not of the type .show(_, _)!")
    case (.show(let lError, let lDuration), .show(let rError, let rDuration)):
        XCTAssertEqual(lDuration, rDuration, file: file, line: line)
        let expectedError = try XCTUnwrap(lError as? ErrorType, file: file, line: line)
        try XCTAssertEqualGenericError(expectedError, rError, file: file, line: line)
    default: return
    }
}
```

Thanks again.